# Where exactly is the Forbidding?

Tags: parallel-universe, shannara

In The Elfstones of Shannara, the demons emerge from some point beyond the west boundary of the Westland, which is claimed by Allanon to be 'the weakest point in the Forbidding'.

In Jarka Ruus, it is revealed that The Forbidding is a world parallel to the main world of The Four Lands, like a mirror image.

In the Dark Legacy series, it is again somewhere beyond the Breakline mountains west of the Westland.

Is there any in-universe reference (Author's remarks, wikia, etc.) that explains these inconsistencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Forbidding is a parallel prison dimension.** The spot where the demons continuously emerge - the Hoare Flats, near the Breakline mountains - as Allanon states, is simply a weak spot that they can make use of to make crossing between worlds, or breaking out, easier.

Allanon explains in Chapter Eight of *Elfstones*:

> For our purposes here it is only important that you know that the evil ones were defeated.  Their power was broken and they were driven back and finally trapped. Those who had defeated them used their powers to create a Forbidding, a wall of imprisonment behind which the evil was to be placed.  Their prison was not of this world nor any world, but a black hole of emptiness and isolation where nothing but the evil would be permitted to exist.

Many of the references to the existing breach by the Dagda Mor refer to the demons crossing between worlds, so this appears to be consistent with what is portrayed in *Jarka Ruus*.

Comment: Admittedly, I have not yet read *Dark Legacy*, so if there's some further discrepancy, I'm not aware of it.

Comment: In the Dark Legacy, it is clearly defined as 'Parallel prison dimension'

Comment: And weak spots can be in different places